# how to post in frontend using ACF form

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, advanced-custom-fields

```
<?php 

    acf_form_head();
    get_header();

?>
<div id="content">

    <?php

        acf_form(array(
            'post_id'       => 'new_post',
            'post_title'    => true,
            'post_content'  => true,
            'new_post'      => array(
                'post_type'     => 'event',
                'post_status'   => 'publish'
            )
        ));

    ?>
</div>
```

Im using this code for displaying frontend post type for user but i'm getting an error and keeping this :

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in
>   /home2/mindblow/public_html/programming/sample-project/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/api.php
>   on line 1185

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: Advanced Custom Field By Elliot Condon Version 4.4.11 @JigarShah

Comment: check these urls: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/using-acf_form-to-create-a-new-post/ and https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-form-error-messages/

Comment: thankyou mate @JigarShah